# Which notification sends Deezer mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, deezer

I'm currently developing a miniplayer app for controling some music player apps on mac os (iTunes, Spotify..) using scripting bridge with Objective-c.
Now I would like to add support for the Deezer Mac App but I can't find the name of the notification send by Deezer app if the player state changed. This is for set an observer in `NSNotificationcenter`.
For Spotify is it e.g. `"com.spotify.client.PlaybackStateChanged"`.
Can anyone tell me this name?

Answer (score 0):

The status of the player is available through the Apple Script :

*Application -> player state.*

It is actually a boolean style variable (**true**: playing / **false**: not playing).

**Note:** You can see all the available info if you open the dictionary with Apple Script Editor:

*File > Open the dictionary > Select Deezer.app*

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I'll try.